# R: Maximum Likelihood Estimation where parameters influence logL indirectly

Tags: r, optimization, estimation

I am an economics student attempting to do somewhat of an unorthodox maximum likelihood estimation of the paramters of a labor market model.

I basically have two equations. One first order condition (16) and a log likelihood function, that I wish to maximize wrt. (alpha,delta,gamma). The variables (w, T, n, x, P) are some data for firm-observations i = 1, ... , 1470.

[Eq. 16 - must hold for all observations i=1,2, ...,1470](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI3Fl.jpg)

[log Likelihood function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzdLD.jpg)

The tricky thing is that I have to compute the values for the product `lambda*s_i` via (16) by assuming some initial value for (alpha,gamma) and then use an identifying restriction that for the largest observation i = 1470, that

```
 s_1470 = 0
```

By doing this eq. (16) has only 1 unknown for (i=1469), which I can solve for using the `uniroot` command in R. Afterwards i can solve for (i=1468) and so on recursively until (i=1).

Having done this operation, I then wish to maximize the log-likelihood function wrt. (alpha,delta,gamma). The crucial thing here is that I could only solve (16) by assuming some initial values for (alpha,gamma).

My problem is that I cannot seem to make R understand, that it should maximize the likelihood function taking into account, that (alpha,gamma) impacts the likelihood-function through it's effect on the (lambda*s_i)'s calculated via (16).

I use the following code. I've coded a function `search_solve` that does the calculation of the (lambda*s_i)'s and stores them in `lambdas`. `logpdfb` calculates the term in brackets, in the likelihood-function.

```
## Likelihoodfunction

loglik<-function(theta,n,x,netwage)
{
  delta <- exp(theta[1])
  alpha <- exp(theta[2])
  gam <- exp(theta[3])

  lambdas = matrix(0,nrow(netwage),1)
  lambdas <- search_solve(netwage,p)

  d <- 1*delta + lambdas * (1-p)
  d2 <- exp(-d)
  b = logpdfb(x,d2,n)

  logl <- colSums(b)
  return(-logl)
}

#STARTING VALUE PARAMETERS
start <- matrix(0,3,1);
start[1,1] = -2;
start[2,1] = -5;
start[3,1] = 0.5;

###################################

optim(start,fn=loglik,n=size,x=stayer,netwage=netwage,method="BFGS",hessian = TRUE)
```

When I use this code R does not optimize wrt. to (alpha,gamma) and the estimates reported are just equal to the starting values.

```
          [,1]
[1,] -1.336792
[2,] -5.000000
[3,]  0.500000
```

How can I make R understand that it should optimize the likelihood-function taking into account that (alpha,gamma) impacts the likelihood-function indirectly?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if we could run your code without error. For example, I do not know where the functions search_solve and logpdfb come from.